# What is timestamp format of iptables recent proc-file?

Tags: iptables, timestamp

I want to understand meaning of records in `/proc/net/xt_recent/ip_list` file (which is created by `recent` extension of `iptables`), e.g:

```
src=127.0.0.1 ttl: 128 last_seen: 4298627364 oldest_pkt: 3 4298623492, 4298625777, 4298627364
```

All fields look pretty obvious and `last_look` look like timestamp. But it isn't timestamp in UNIX-time format. Being converted as UNIX-time is equal 03/21/2106 18:19:24. Evidently it isn't a "last seen" time.

How can I extract correct value from `last_seen` time?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Just to avoid misconception:

```
$ date 
Mon Jun 15 14:14:00 MSK 2015
```

Comment: http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showpost.php?p=1235507&postcount=2

Comment: I struggled with for a while before I found this utility on github https://github.com/peppelinux/iptables_xt_recent_parser that is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should works:

```
FILE=iplist #This is file name of recent module output. It may vary on your system (like iplist)
TICKS=$(grep CONFIG_HZ= /boot/config-$(uname -r)|awk -F= '{print $2}') # Get current ticks per sec

printit()
{
    Len=`echo $1|wc -c`
    Date=$DATE
    Dot="."
    Loop=`echo 50-$Len|bc`
    loop=0
    while [ $loop -le $Loop ]
    do
        loop=`echo $loop+1|bc`
        Dot=`echo $Dot.`
    done
    echo "$1$Dot$DATE"
}
cat $FILE|while read LINE
do
    IP=`echo $LINE|awk '{print $1}'|awk -F= {'print $2'}`
    DATE=$(date -d@$(date +'%s'-$(echo \($(cat /proc/timer_list|grep -m1 -E '^jiffies'|cut -d" " -f2)-$(awk '{print $5}' $FILE)\)/$TICKS|bc)|bc))
    printit $IP $DATE
done
```

And there is an output of your example:

```
127.0.0.1..........................................Пн. мая 18 14:24:40 OMST 2015
```

Timezone may differ from you regional settings

Also you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731463/converting-jiffies-to-milli-seconds

Comment: It just interpret `last_seen` value as POSIX-timestamp and print it in human-readable format -- I again see datetime in distant 2106 year. :(

Comment: I've edited answer, check please

Comment: I don't know Bash so well, but unfortunately it looks like your script just output current datetime -- I ran it three times and got three sequential datetimes close to current datetime (but `ip_list` didn't change). Do you wish to tell `last_seen` value is stored in jiffies?

Comment: Yes, in jiffies since boot. I fixed code, so now it work normal

Comment: Yeah, it works! But there is not `/boot/config*` on my system (Arch). I think it is better to take HZ from `/proc/config.gz`. I did it this way.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote this:

https://github.com/peppelinux/xt_recent_parser

output is like this:

```
python3 xt_recent_parser.py 
XT_RECENT python parser
<giuseppe.demarco@unical.it>


114.241.108.160, last seen: 2017-03-25 18:21:42 after 13 Connections 
46.165.210.17, last seen: 2017-03-25 13:07:54 after 10 Connections 
61.53.219.162, last seen: 2017-03-25 17:39:17 after 20 Connections 
179.37.141.232, last seen: 2017-03-25 18:08:23 after 2 Connections 
114.42.117.39, last seen: 2017-03-25 13:22:14 after 18 Connections 
177.12.84.234, last seen: 2017-03-25 16:22:14 after 17 Connections
```

Comment: Great!  Seven years later...  [ devuan iptables 1.8.9-2 kernel 6.1.0-13-arm64 AND iptables 1.8.7-1 kernel 5.10.0-26-686 ]

Answer (score 2):

That's a number of *jiffies*, which is an internal kernel variable incremented every 1/HZ seconds. As shown by Maxiko, you can get the current `jiffies` value from `/proc/timer_list`. You can generally get `HZ` from `/boot/config.<kernel-version>`, so you should be able to post-process that data with something like:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use Time::HiRes qw(gettimeofday);
use POSIX;

my $kernel = (uname())[2];

open CONFIG, "<", "/boot/config-$kernel" or
  die "Can't find kernel config file: $!";

my $hz;
while (<CONFIG>) {
  if (/^CONFIG_HZ=(\d+)/) {
    $hz = $1;
    last;
  }
}
close CONFIG;

die "Can't determine HZ" unless $hz;

open TIMERS, "<", "/proc/timer_list" or
  die "Can't open /proc/timer_list: $!";

my $jiffies;
while (<TIMERS>) {
  if (/^jiffies: (\d+)/) {
    $jiffies = $1;
    last;
  }
}
close TIMERS;

die "Can't determine jiffies" unless $jiffies;

my ($seconds, $microseconds) = gettimeofday;
$seconds += $microseconds / 1e6;

while (<>) {
  s{(?<=last_seen: )\d+|\d+(?=,|$)}{
    my $t = $seconds + ($& - $jiffies) / $hz;
    $& . strftime(" [%F %T", localtime($t)) .
      sprintf(".%03d]", ($t * 1000 + 0.5) % 1000);
  }ge;
  print;
}
```

Which on your sample and on my system (so with a different jiffies as on yours) gives:

```
src=127.0.0.1 ttl: 128 last_seen: 4298627364 [2016-08-16 17:21:00.882] oldest_pkt: 3 4298623492 [2016-08-16 17:20:45.394], 4298625777 [2016-08-16 17:20:54.534], 4298627364 [2016-08-16 17:21:00.882]
```